# regex find character parse until space or period

Tags: regex

I have a chunk of text which may include a social media account. I want that account without the trailing space or period. This is using google sheets and `regextract`. So far, I still get the period returned (if it exists). I'm searching for `@` then want to return all text until space or period.

Here's my formula:

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(E2,"@"),REGEXEXTRACT(E2,"@.*?\s"),"No social handle")
```

`E2` is the cell that I'm searching. Here's a sample text: `Former foo, now blah blah blahr @socialaccount. blah blah blah blah foo.`

Comment: according to my research, `@.*?\s` does in fact match that string

Answer (score 1):

You can use as this:

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(E2,"@"),REGEXEXTRACT(E2,"@.+?\b"),"No social handle")
```

It captures everything non greedy until a word boundary `\b` is found. I tested it in My own Google Spreadsheets.

**Some explanation**

The way the formula `REGEXEXTRACT` works is to extract everything from the start of the regex pattern until the last character to the regex pattern e.g.:

- `REGEXEXTRACT("bla ble bli", "b?e")` this will find anything in the given string that starts with a `b` and ends with an `e`, therefore it will return `ble`
- `REGEXEXTRACT("bla bleble bli", "b.+e")` this will find anything in the given string that starts with a `b` plus any character (greedy) until it finds an `e`, therefore it will return `bleble`
- `REGEXEXTRACT("bla bleble bli", "b.+?e")` this will find anything in the given string that starts with a `b` plus any character (non greedy) until the first occurrence of an `e`, therefore it will return `ble`

That special `\b` is called a [**Word Boundary**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (detailed article on it, enjoy)

And the full explanation for the regex I provided:

```
 @ matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)
   .+? matches any character (except for line terminators)
    +? Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few 
                    times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
 \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

- Explanation from [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8T4TlP/1)

Comment: Hi there, was this answer useful to you? If so, please consider in accepting it. You do so by clicking in the V icon at the left side of this panel.

Comment: Thank you. Sure wish I understood how this works. It's like magic. (Am searching for a good reference.)

Comment: Let me edit it adding some explanation mainly about the `\b`

Comment: @BrickMarcom Take a look :) enjoy

Comment: Hi there @BrickMarcom Please consider in accepting it if it was helpful to you. To do so, click on the V icon in the left side of this answer. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `@.*?\s` with

```
@\S+\b
```

This will match:

- `@` - a `@` char
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars, as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary position.

As `\b` appears after `\S+`, it means that all *trailing* non-word chars other than whitespaces will be cut off the match value.

See [regex example](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4X7x/1).